# Как узнать какой язык на сайте и потом изменить стиль объекта в зависимости от языка страницы

Tags: php, html, css

Ситуация такая, на сайте реализована смена языка.
Задача: сделать так, чтобы при выборе русского или английского выделялся значок того, какой элемент выбран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. если выбран русский, то флажок как-то должен выделяться и с английским аналогичная история.
Код выглядит так.
Вопрос: как это возможно реализовать? Пытался гуглить ничего не нашел дельного.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="menumob">
    <li class="programs">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/includes/img/Flag_of_Russia (1) 1.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="programs">
      <a href="/en/main">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/includes/img/s1201.png" style="opacity: 0.7;">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: В базу данных при смене языка для определенного пользователя вписывайте значение этого самого языка. Для выбора языка через php делаете проверку - какой язык указан у этого юзера и выводите нужный результат.

Answer (score 0):

При выборе языка меняется *состояние* -- факт, что выбран определенный язык.
состояние можно хранить в разных местах, в зависимости от задачи:

- URL
- Cookie
- сессия PHP
- запись пользователя в БД

А при формировании HTML это состояние можно доставать и использовать.

И это общий принцип -- 2 шага: действие меняет состояние, затем состояние отображается в HTML. Реализуется принцип по-разному, например, как POST-redirect-GET: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get